# Usage of callback functions and asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js

I am working with a `node.js` application that uses Facebook APIs. In one part of my code I need to return the `access_token` from a common function. That is, a lot of other functions need to call this function to retrieve the Facebook access token.

Below is my code:

```
function getAccesstoken(code) {
    var options = {
        host: 'graph.facebook.com',        
        path: '/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxx&code='+code.toString()
    };

    var acc_token = ''

    https.get(options, function(resp) {
        resp.on('data', function(d) {                                    
            acc_token = acc_token+d.toString()
        });    

        resp.on('end', function() {
            var expiry_index = acc_token.indexOf('&expires=')

            acc_token = acc_token.substring(0, expiry_index)            
        });
    });        

    return acc_token.toString()
}
```

Since `https.get` call is asynchronous, function always returns an empty string. What should be the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you concerned that another part of your system will ask for the `access_token` and you won't have it, or you don't know how to proceed realizing you need to model something you're not familiar with (event-driven programming)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well supply a callback function to your getAccesToken function and call the function after the response has ended and pass acc_token to that function..

```
 function getAccessToken(code,cb){
    .....
    resp.on('end',function(){
       .....
       cb(null,acc_token)
    })
 }
```

then call your function like

```
getAccesToken("whatever",function(err,token){
  console.log("got token", token)
})
```

Comment: Thanks supernova, It's Time to learn the power of callbacks :)

Answer (score 0):

You've already answered the question in your title - use a callback.

Define another variable for `getAccesstoken` that should be a function that gets called when `acc_token` is filled, and pass `acc_token` as an argument for that function to use.

It's the same way that `https.get` is working - the second argument is a function that's called when the request is completed, and gets passed the result of the request.